# CDate can't convert from string dd/MM/yyyyy in Report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

`06/07/2559` < this is `dd/MM/yyyy`

This is ok for converting but `CDate` convert to this format `MM/dd/yyyy`

If I use this
`30/06/2559` I'll get **error** because `CDate` think `30` is a month.

Anyway to convert my string `dd/MM/yyyy` to `Date` in Report?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways/things that you can do to achieve this -

1. You can set the localisation format at the report level which means you don't have to use the format function every time you drop a date on to the report.
   [image]
2. You can covert the string to your required format ('mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy') in database itself. For your reference in MSSQL you can do it like this - 
   [image]
3. You can format (use `FORMAT()` function) your code in SSRS itself somewhat like below - 
   [image]

Comment: Really Thank for this you saved my life

Answer (score 1):

On that field change attibute Language to `es-Es` (or any other country that uses dd/MM/yyyy format)